# undefined columns selected for spearman correlation

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a spearman correlation test, but when i try to do the test R returns that I have undefined columns selected. Yet all the column names that I use are in the data (see colnames). How do I refer correctly to my columns?

```
> colnames(data)
 [1] "Species"       "Limanda"       "Merlangius"    "Pleuronectes"  "Depth"        
 [6] "Temperature"   "Salinty"       "Density"       "DebitCUFES"    "Sediment"     
[11] "llimanda"      "lmerlangius"   "lpleuronectes"

> cor(data[,c("Temperature", "Salinity", "Depth", "Sediment", "llimanda", "lmerlangius", "lpleuronectes")], use="complete.obs", method="spearman")
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c("Temperature", "Salinity", "Depth", 
>   :    undefined columns selected

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the output `colnames(data)` contains "Salinty" and not "Salinity"

Comment: Dear tds, i noticed that but changing it, doesn't change a thing.